# Joining Multiple tables into a dynamic table with Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, pivot

This code now displays information from multiple tables, that are pivoted
Ok, so this code now works almost as I want it to (working currently on something with it, no further questions atm):

```
if (exists (select * from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = '##tempz'))
begin
drop table ##tempz
end
else
DECLARE @startDate datetime
DECLARE @enddate datetime
DECLARE @registernum int
DECLARE @storename varchar(20)
DECLARE @cashiername varchar(20)
SET @startDate = '1/1/2011'
SET @enddate = '1/1/2013'
SET @registernum = 01
SET @storename = '01'
SET @cashiername = 'admin'

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.CurrencyDesc)
FROM rpPay p LEFT JOIN RPTrs r ON p.ReceiptNo = r.ReceiptNo LEFT JOIN Currencies c ON c.POSCurrency = LEFT(p.paytype,1)
WHERE r.trsdate >= @startDate AND r.trsdate <= @enddate
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SELECT @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(c.CurrencyDesc) +', 0) as '+ QUOTENAME(c.CurrencyDesc)
FROM rpPay p LEFT JOIN RPTrs r ON p.ReceiptNo = r.ReceiptNo LEFT JOIN Currencies c ON LEFT(p.paytype,1) = c.POSCurrency
WHERE r.trsdate >= @startDate AND r.trsdate <= @enddate
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

--select @cols, @colsnull

SET @query = 'select date, cashregister, storeid, cashier, '+@colsNull+' into ##tempz
FROM
(SELECT cast(r.trsdate AS DATE) date,c.CurrencyDesc,p.amount,r.cashregister,r.storeid,r.cashier
FROM rpPay p LEFT JOIN RPTrs r ON p.ReceiptNo = r.receiptno LEFT JOIN Currencies c ON LEFT(p.paytype,1) = c.POSCurrency
WHERE r.trsdate >= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @startDate, 101) +''' AND r.trsdate <= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @endDate, 101) +''' 
) p
pivot
(sum(amount) FOR CurrencyDesc in('+@cols+')) piv'
execute(@query)

select * from ##tempz
```

Comment: Let's start with what RDBMS you are using

Comment: Posting your full table structure would be very helpful

Comment: MsSQL 2008, rpPay has storeID, PayType, amount. Currencies has POSCurrency (which is the same as rpPay.PayType), CurrencyDesc. RPTrs has storeID, trsdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but I am assuming SQL Server based on your previous questions.  Based on the limited details, you can `PIVOT` the data.

If you know the values ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values using a static pivot:

```
select *
from
(
    select 
        cast(r.trsdate as DATE) date,
        c.CurrencyDesc,
        p.amount
    from rpPay p
    left join RPTrs r
        on p.id = r.id
    left join Currencies c
        on p.PayType = c.PayType
    where r.trsdate >= @startDate 
        and r.trsdate <= @enddate
) src
pivot
(
    sum(amount)
    for CurrencyDesc in (Amex, Cash, Visa, Check, [Gift Card])
) piv
```

If the values are unknown, then you can use dynamic sql:

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @enddate datetime
  set @startDate = '1/1/12'
 set @enddate = '1/1/13'
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.CurrencyDesc) 
                    from rpPay p
                    left join RPTrs r
                        on p.id = r.id
                    left join Currencies c
                        on p.PayType = c.PayType
                    where r.trsdate >= @startDate 
                        and r.trsdate <= @enddate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
    = 'select date, '+@cols+'
       from
       (
         select 
            cast(r.trsdate as DATE) date,
            c.CurrencyDesc,
            p.amount
        from rpPay p
        left join RPTrs r
            on p.id = r.id
        left join Currencies c
            on p.PayType = c.PayType
        where r.trsdate >= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @startDate, 101) +'''
            and r.trsdate <= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @endDate, 101) +'''
       ) p
       pivot
       (
          sum(amount)
          for CurrencyDesc in('+@cols+')
       ) piv'

execute(@query)
```

Edit #1, based on your edited question you can use:

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @enddate datetime
declare @registernum int
declare @storename int
declare @cashiername varchar(20)
set @startDate = '1/1/2012'
set @enddate = '1/1/2013'
set @registernum = 01
set @storename = '01'
set @cashiername = 'admin'

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.CurrencyDesc) 
                        from rpPay p 
                        left join RPTrs r 
                            on p.ReceiptNo = r.ReceiptNo 
                        left join Currencies c 
                            on p.PayType = c.POSCurrency
                        where r.trsdate >= @startDate and r.trsdate <= @enddate
                            and cashregister = @registernum
                            and r.storeid = @storename
                            and cashier = @cashiername
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(c.CurrencyDesc) +', 0) as '+ QUOTENAME(c.CurrencyDesc)
                        from rpPay p 
                        left join RPTrs r 
                            on p.ReceiptNo = r.ReceiptNo 
                        left join Currencies c 
                            on p.PayType = c.POSCurrency
                        where r.trsdate >= @startDate and r.trsdate <= @enddate
                            and cashregister = @registernum
                            and r.storeid = @storename
                            and cashier = @cashiername
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

--select @cols, @colsnull

set @query = 'select date, cashregister, storeid, cashier, '+@colsNull+'
                from
                (
                    select cast(r.trsdate as DATE) date,
                        c.CurrencyDesc,
                        p.amount,
                        r.cashregister,
                        r.storeid,
                        r.cashier 
                    from rpPay p 
                    left join RPTrs r 
                        on p.ReceiptNo = r.receiptno 
                    left join Currencies c 
                        on p.PayType = c.POSCurrency
                    where r.trsdate >= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @startDate, 101) +''' 
                        and r.trsdate <= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @endDate, 101) +''' 
                        and cashregister = '''+cast(@registernum as varchar(10))+''' 
                        and r.storeid = '''+cast(@storename as varchar(50))+''' 
                        and r.cashier = '''+@cashiername+''' 
                ) p
                pivot
                (
                    sum(amount) 
                    for CurrencyDesc in('+@cols+')
                ) piv'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8eb07/18)

Comment: I get these errors : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Cash'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' 
                ) p
pivot
(sum(amount) for CurrencyDesc in([Cash],[MasterCard],[Off Line C.Card],[C.Card],[Str Cr],[Visa/MC],[Cash Change],[Gift Card],[Amex])) piv'.

Comment: Can you edit your OP with your table structure and some sample data?  It is hard to see exactly what your table structure is.

Comment: @JohnZ see my edit, I also added a demo with the sample data that you provided

Comment: @bluefeet Thank you, I got it to work and it is amazing. Your help is greatly appreciated and saved me a lot of time.